A curve in a single orbit in the space of Riemannian metrics
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $\mathcal M$ denote the collection of all Riemannian metrics on $M$. There is a right action of the product group $\mathbb R^+ \times \text{Diff}(M)$ on $\mathcal M$ via
$$(c,\varphi) \cdot h := c \varphi^* h.$$
Let $I$ be an open interval containing zero, and let $g:I \times M \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$ be a smooth map such that $g(t):M \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$ is a Riemannian metric for all $t \in I$. Suppose the curve $g:I \rightarrow \mathcal M$ lies in a single orbit of the action described above. Then clearly there exist maps $c:I \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ and $\varphi:I \rightarrow \text{Diff}(M)$ such that $g(t) = c(t)(\varphi(t)^*g(0))$ for all $t \in I$.
Question. Does there exist smooth $c:I \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ and a smooth family of diffeomorphisms $\varphi:I \times M \rightarrow M$ such that $g(t) = c(t)(\varphi(t)^*g(0))$ for all $t \in I$?
Context. A Ricci soliton is a Riemannian metric $g_0$ such that there exist $\lambda \in\mathbb R$ and a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ for which
$$\text{Ric}(g_0) = \lambda g_0 + \mathcal L_X g_0.$$
Suppose $g_0$ is a Ricci soliton with $\lambda$ and $X$ as above, with $X$ complete. Then $g_0$ induces a solution to the Ricci flow $g:I \rightarrow \mathcal M$ which remains in the same orbit of the action described in the first paragraph: Let $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ be the open interval where  $c(t) := 1-2 \lambda t$ is positive. Let $\tau:I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the smooth function such that $\tau(0) = 1$ and $\tau' = 1/c$. Let $\theta:\mathbb R \times M \rightarrow M$ be the flow of $X$. Let $\varphi:I \times M \rightarrow M$ be the smooth family of diffeomorphisms given by $\varphi(t,p) := \theta(\tau(t),p)$. Then it is straightforward to check that $g:I \rightarrow \mathcal M$ given by $g(t) := c(t) \varphi(t)^* g_0$ is a solution to the Ricci flow.
I've read in many textbooks about the Ricci flow that Ricci solitons are the fixed points of the Ricci flow in the sense that the solution stays in the same orbit. The previous paragraph gives one direction: a Ricci soliton induces a Ricci flow solution which remains in the same orbit. I would like to prove the converse: if a Ricci flow solution $g:I \rightarrow \mathcal M$ remains in the same orbit, then $g(0)$ is a Ricci soliton. I am stuck on showing that there exist smooth $c$ and $\varphi$ as described in the question.
